# Registering Service Worker in a different folder

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker

I am trying to figure how to register properly service worker, in development all works fine, I call service worker:

```
if (navigator.serviceWorker) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js').then(function(reg) {
        if (reg.waiting) {
            reg.waiting.postMessage({ action: 'skipWaiting' });
            return;
        }

        reg.addEventListener('updatefound', function() {
            trackInstalling(reg.installing);
        });

        var refreshing;
        navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange', function() {
            if (refreshing) return;
            window.location.reload();
            refreshing = true;
        });

    });

}
```

Cache is listed like this:

```
var urlsToCache = [
    '/',
    '/index.html',
    '/css/app.min.css',
    '/js/app.min.js',
    '/js/library.min.js',
    '/views/line.html',
    '/views/start.html',
    '/views/station.html',
    '/views/timetable.html'
];
```

This is just a project I am doing for Udacity so the page won't have it's own domain. However I still want to keep the final version on-line in a folder /train/ but service worker is registered under the main domain so is caching wrong files.

If I add `'train/index.html'`the service worker is looking for `'train/train/index.html'`. Same happens if try to register service worker in a folder "train"...

How should I do it so the on-line version of the project works properly?

Comment: Have you tried making the cache URLs relative (i.e. removing the preceding slash?)  The results you got from adding `'train/index.html'` would indicate that this is probably what you want.

Comment: really... That was easy... :) Yes, it worked

Comment: Put it in an answer I will up vote it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your service worker will now live in a subfolder of the domain, its cache paths should be relative:

```
var urlsToCache = [
    './',  // I'm not 100% sure on the syntax for this one. In your case
           // '/train/' would definitely work, but it would require updating
           // if you ever move the app to a different folder.

    'index.html', // All the other URLs just lose their preceding slash.
    'css/app.min.css',
    'js/app.min.js',
    'js/library.min.js',
    'views/line.html',
    'views/start.html',
    'views/station.html',
    'views/timetable.html'
];
```

Comment: Both `./` and `.` are valid.